# Loop SQL SELECT with changing parameters from a dataframe in R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I would like to know whether it is possible to build a SQL SELECT query in R which would change the WHERE parameters at every run of a loop and take them from a separate R dataframe.

I parameter dataframe [df_params] which looks like this:

```
group   person   date_from             date_to
1        Mike    2020-10-01 12:00:00   2020-10-01 13:00:00
2        Mike    2020-10-04 09:00:00   2020-10-07 17:00:00
3        Dave    2020-10-07 12:00:00   2020-10-07 13:00:00
4        Dave    2020-10-09 09:00:00   2020-10-11 17:00:00
```

My idea was something like this:

```
dflist_new<-list()
suppressWarnings({
for (group in df_params) {
  suppressWarnings({
  rs = dbSendQuery(connect_replica(), paste("
                                SELECT *
                                FROM classroom_table 
                                WHERE person = ",person," AND timestamp >= ",date_from," AND timestamp <= ",date_to,"
                                
                               ", sep=''))
                  })
  df_groups<- fetch(rs, n=-1)
  if ((is.data.frame(df_groups) && nrow(df_groups)==0) ==TRUE){
    next
  }
  dflist_new[[group]] <- df_groups
  disconnect_replica()
}})
```

This however does not work and ends up in an error message saying that the objects from the WHERE clause could not be found.
I used a similar setup with a list of values changing only 1 parameter at each run. Now I need to change more parameters for each "group".

Is something like this possible in R.
Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, but first: you may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query.

First, using `DBI::dbBind`:

```r
qry <- "select * from classroom_table where person=? and timestamp between ? and ?"
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, qry)
rets <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(rn) DBI::dbFetch(DBI::dbBind(res, df[rn,2:4])))
```

Forming each query, though, can be done using `DBI::sqlInterpolate`:

```r
qry <- "select * from classroom_table where person=?person and timestamp between ?date_from and ?date_to"
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(rn) DBI::sqlInterpolate(con, qry, .dots = df[rn,2:4]))
# [[1]]
# <SQL> select * from classroom_table where person='Mike' and timestamp between '2020-10-01 12:00:00' and '2020-10-01 13:00:00'
# [[2]]
# <SQL> select * from classroom_table where person='Mike' and timestamp between '2020-10-04 09:00:00' and '2020-10-07 17:00:00'
# [[3]]
# <SQL> select * from classroom_table where person='Dave' and timestamp between '2020-10-07 12:00:00' and '2020-10-07 13:00:00'
# [[4]]
# <SQL> select * from classroom_table where person='Dave' and timestamp between '2020-10-09 09:00:00' and '2020-10-11 17:00:00'
```

and you can run each query individually.